# Converting an SQLite command to an appropriate contentResolver query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have this SQL query, and since I'm willing to use `content://sms/inbox` I can't pass it using rawQuery, and will have to use a contentResolver. And I have no idea how to do that.

It's supposed to return the most recent SMS recieved for each number.

Here's the SQL, if you can help me with that :/

```
SELECT adress, id, date /*Columns from the SMS contentResolver*/
FROM sms_databse /*Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"); ????*/
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "s"
FROM sms_databse /*Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"); ????*/
WHERE s.adress = sms_database.adress
AND s.date <= sms_database.date
)
<=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The content resolver interface does not allow arbitrary queries (as allowed by `rawQuery()`), but is modelled on the simpler `query()` function.

The simple interface allows the content resolver implementation to check that the client does not try to access forbidden data; this would not be possible if arbitrary SQL were allowed.

If you want to do complex processing on the data, you have get all the data, and do it yourself.

Comment: So there is no way to have a subquery when using query () ? In that case how should i proceed?